# How to set information in xml from a model of Data Binding in attributes of a custom view

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-custom-view

There are two custom attributes.

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomImageView">
        <attr name="customTitle" format="reference" />
        <attr name="customDrawableImage" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

```
<import type="java.util.List"/>
        <variable
            name="models"
            type="List&lt;com.full.path.package.model.Model&gt;" />

<com.full.path.packages.test.CustomImageView
            android:id="@+id/choice_quality_awful_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"          
            app:customTitle="@{models.get(0).title}"/>
```

There isn't mistake in attrs or logic Data Binding, because I can set another string in `app:customTitle` and it'll be work. And if I set `models.get(0).title` in other textView it'll be work. 
But after running I have following error (Android Studio thinks that customTitle is naming of Bidning adapter and tries to find it)

```
Cannot find a setter for <com.lucid.dreaming.ui.choicequality.views.QualityImageView app:qualityTitle> that accepts parameter type 'int'

If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
```

How can I mark, that it isn't Binding Adapter?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
app:customTitle="@={model.title}"
```

insted of

```
app:customTitle="@{model.title}"
```

Comment: I don't know how can help me two-way binding, but I tried it and it didn't help me. By the way, maybe it depends on list of models. (I change question, because it doesn't wok with list)